# SSL handshake error with trusting all server certificates

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, handshake, trust

I have the following code to make a SOAP over HTTPS protocol while trusting all certificates. But I am getting SSL handshake error.

While the code runs fine on Windows 7, with JRE 1.6.
The same code fails to run on Unix AIX, with JRE 1.6.

```
package unsecureBackup;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class SendSomaCommand {
    //Code to Allow Opening insecure HTTPS Connection
    //Allowing all DataPower XML Management Interface Cert to create Connection without it's validation
    static{
        try{
            TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = { new X509TrustManager() {
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }

                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs,
                        String authType) {
                }

                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs,
                        String authType) {
                }
            } };
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");

            HostnameVerifier hv = new HostnameVerifier() {
                public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
                    return true;
                }
            };
            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hv);
        }catch(Exception exception){
            System.err.println(exception);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        //Url - https://dpdev02.dev.anz:5550/service/mgmt/current

        //SomaRequest.xml contains Soma XML Request (See the other attachment)      
        String output = sendRequest("https://IP:5550/service/mgmt/current", "getfile.xml", "Username", "Password");
        System.out.println(output);
    }


    /**
     * Send GetFileStore Request with location "local:" to DataPower box to file local file system
     * @param pUrl
     * @param pXmlFile2Send
     * @param pDomain
     * @param pUsername
     * @param pPassword
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     * 
     */
    public static String sendRequest(String pUrl, String pXmlFile2Send, String pUsername, String pPassword) throws Exception {
        String SOAPUrl      = pUrl;
        String xmlFile2Send = pXmlFile2Send;
        String SOAPAction = "";


        // Create the connection where we're going to send the file.
        URL url = new URL(SOAPUrl);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        HttpsURLConnection httpConn = (HttpsURLConnection) connection;

        // Open the input file. After we copy it to a byte array, we can see
        // how big it is so that we can set the HTTP Content-Length
        // property. (See complete e-mail below for more on this.)
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(xmlFile2Send);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        // Copy the SOAP file to the open connection.
        copy(fin,bout);
        fin.close();

        //Replace domainName in Request
        String soapRequest = bout.toString();

        //Convert into bytes
        byte[] b = soapRequest.getBytes();

        // Set the appropriate HTTP parameters.
        httpConn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length",String.valueOf( b.length ) );
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","text/xml; charset=utf-8");
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction",SOAPAction);

        //Create UsernamePassword 
        //To Base64 decoding, Apache common-codec is used.
        String authString = pUsername + ":" + pPassword;
        byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes());
        String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);

        //httpConn.setRequestProperty("Authorization","Basic Z295YWxyYWRtaW46VHJhbnNmZXIxMiM=");
        httpConn.setRequestMethod( "POST" );
        httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
        httpConn.setDoInput(true);

        // Everything's set up; send the XML that was read in to b.
        OutputStream out = httpConn.getOutputStream();
        out.write(b);    
        out.close();

        // Read the response and write it to standard out.
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(httpConn.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);

        String inputLine;
        String output = "";
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
            output = output+inputLine;
        }

        in.close();
        return output;
    }

    // copy method from From E.R. Harold's book "Java I/O"
    public static void copy(InputStream in, OutputStream out) 
            throws IOException {

        // do not allow other threads to read from the
        // input or write to the output while copying is
        // taking place
        synchronized (in) {
            synchronized (out) {

                byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
                while (true) {
                    int bytesRead = in.read(buffer);
                    if (bytesRead == -1) break;
                    out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at com.ibm.jsse2.o.a(o.java:22)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.o.a(o.java:34)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.b(SSLSocketImpl.java:378)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:479)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.h(SSLSocketImpl.java:437)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:142)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:686)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.c.afterConnect(c.java:98)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.d.connect(d.java:13)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1014)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.b.getOutputStream(b.java:25)
    at unsecureBackup.SendSomaCommand.sendRequest(SendSomaCommand.java:125)
    at unsecureBackup.SendSomaCommand.main(SendSomaCommand.java:64)
```

Comment: A fatal handshake alert from the server is not related to certificate validation but more to ciphers, protocol version etc. Compare debug messages from a working and non-working version especially regarding available ciphers and the used protocol version.

Comment: How do I get the cipher and protocol version. I am exporting the project using eclipse and running the jar.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html might help.

Comment: well I got a script to test ciphers.Here are the supported ones

Testing AES256-GCM-SHA384...YES
Testing AES256-SHA256...YES
Testing AES256-SHA...YES
Testing AES128-GCM-SHA256...YES
Testing AES128-SHA256...YES
Testing AES128-SHA...YES
Testing DES-CBC3-SHA...YES
Testing RC4-SHA...YES

Comment: Please add all the details to you question and not as unformatted blob into the comments. Please also add how you got the information and don't forget to provide the client side information you get from SSL debugging.